# Python: How do I remove the formatting when joining items from a list into a string?

Tags: python, string

Good morning, all:

I'm working on a small Python program which matches together small strings in order to make up fictional company names. The name segments are stored in three lists, and a random string from each list is chosen each time a new name is requested. For example, the program might pick "Eli", "rce" and "Softworks" from the three lists, which would give me "Elirce Softworks".

```
seg1 = namesegs1[random.randint(0, seg1_length)]
seg2 = namesegs2[random.randint(0, seg2_length)]
seg3 = namesegs3[random.randint(0, seg3_length)]
new_name = "{0}{1} {2}".format(seg1, seg2, seg3)
```

However, the code actually returns ['Eli']['rce'] ['Softworks']. It makes sense, given that it's joining items from lists, but I don't see why these can't be removed in some way or another.

Here's one way I've made it work:

```
new_name = new_name.replace("'", "")
new_name = new_name.replace(",", "")
new_name = new_name.replace("[", "")
new_name = new_name.replace("]", "")
```

That gets rid of the formatting nicely, but it's less than satisfactory and it feels like I'm doing it wrong. Is there a better way to be going about this?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: What does `namesegs1` contains?

Comment: It's a list of the possible 'chunks' that might come first in the name:

    [['Ar'], ['Bohe'], ['Coe'], ['Del'], ['Eli'], ['Fir'], ['Ghe'], ['Her'], ['Indi']]

Comment: new_name = "{0}{1} {2}".format(*(seg1 + seg2 + seg3))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `namesegs1` is a list of lists rather than a list of strings.

What do you get with the following?

```
new_name = "{0}{1} {2}".format(seg1[0], seg2[0], seg3[0])
```

By the way, use `random.choice(namesegs1)` to select a random item from your list, rather than that thing you've done with `random.randint`.

Comment: That works perfectly: thanks very much!

PS. Thanks also for the advice on random selection. It makes the code much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Python string join functionality?
For me it sounds like what you need.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your logic with the randomizer generates an input list as:
`input_list = [['Eli'],['rce'],['Softworks']]`

the following code will give you what you need:

```
input_list = [i[0] for i in input_list]
''.join(input_list)
```